# Using echo & exit to end a function in php

Tags: php

When I post data to a function in php page, it continues to run over all lines.
I mean while debugging I retrieve my data with `echo json_encode(..)`
And continue in next line to debug. So I use `exit` to stop it. But it means I have to use `exit each echo..`

```
 echo json_encode($resultData);
                exit; //if I don't use this, interprets goes on
```

In real scenario, I though it will improve performance because I don't need php interpreter check the other lines.. 
or I have misunderstood completely on this?

Comment: And the problem is ?

Comment: if the job is done then why other lines?

Comment: @Alex the problem is I wonder Do I have to use exit with echo to send data to client. or is there any more reliable way like in .NET simply "return"

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ `exit` stop the script running further...To send data to client there are too many possible ways.

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ if you want to return data in your function just use `return json_encode($resultData);`

Comment: @Alex I got the point, its more clear now thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To direct the result to the calling function use `return json_encode($resultData);`

If just want to output your results use

```
echo json_encode($resultData);
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it with one function you can use `exit()` or `die()` instead of `echo` + `exit`, for example:

```
exit(json_encode($resultData));
```

or

```
die(json_encode($resultData));
```

They are equivalent to each other, but `die` is one character shorter.